# How to set these 2 banners?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently building a site for a club and I need help fixing the banner. There are 2 banners, 1st banner will be repeated a few times and the 2nd banner will be shown last. For example:

```
[ banner 1 ][ banner 1 ][ banner 1 ][ banner 1 ][ banner 2 ]
```

Banner 1 is basically some decorative that will repeat and banner 2 is the logo.

The problem is I can't get banner #1 to stop repeating so banner #2 can show up. So far,  this is the CSS I'm using:

```
#banner
{   
    background-image    : url(images/banner1.jpg), url(images/banner2.jpg);
    background-repeat   : repeat-x, no-repeat;
    min-height      : 175px;
}
```

Is there a way to make to do it the way I imagined? I have been to this site: http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/ and I'm wondering if I can't repeat it, maybe I can put 1 banner on top the other. I tried using background-position, but the solution didn't work.

Comment: Many questions:
- what browser are you using?
- Can you afford to have the banner2 over banner1, as in banner2 overlapping banner1
- Can you use 2 elements with each their background image?

Comment: Chrome and firefox, yes that was my 2nd suggestion: to put banner 2 over banner 1, not sure what you mean by third question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have two `divs` with their own background

HTML :

```
<div class="banner1">
    <div class="banner2">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.banner1 {
    width: 200px;
    height:50px;
    background: url('http://jsfiddle.net/img/top-bg.png') repeat-x;
}

.banner2 {
    width:50px;
    float:right;
    height: inherit;
    background-color: red;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaL5z/)

It's up to you if you want two divs side by side or one over the other

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the width of the repeating element:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="banner1"></div><div class="banner2"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.banner1, .banner2 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
}
.banner1 {
    width: 75%;
    background: url('http://jsfiddle.net/img/top-bg.png') repeat-x;
}
.banner2 {
    width: 25%;
    background: red;
}
```

**Live demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vj4q6/3/)**